# Tkinter stopping big loop functions

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, process

I've read some of other articles and Q&As about threading, tkinter stop buttons etc. Most of the ideas were about how to stop some small loops. But my problem is that I'm trying to wrap an existing function I created a month ago with my Tkinter GUI. And the existing function is quite huge, so I don't know how I should stop the loop. Here's the code. The Reader object reads an input text file and outputs a csvfile from web scraping results. It extracts all the reviews from an input shopping mall url. You can ignore all the Korean, it's no important. There's another object called, 'SmartStoreReviewScraper' but the function is real simple. It basically request GET a json file gives it back to the Reader so it can convert into a csvfile.

```
class Reader:
def __init__(self, filename, limit=None, delay_time=0):
    self.filename = filename
    self.limit = limit
    self.delay_time = delay_time
    self.target_variable = ['평점', '아이디', '시간', '구매옵션', '리뷰내용']
    self.read_input_file()
    self.extract_file()

def read_input_file(self):
    request_df = pd.read_csv(self.filename, names=['names', 'link'], sep='*')
    request_df = request_df.set_index('names')
    request_df.index = request_df.index + request_df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')
    request_df.to_csv('output/wd.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=False)

def extract_file(self):
    df = pd.read_csv('output/wd.csv', encoding='utf-8', names=['names', 'link'])
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        
        file_name = list(df['names'])[i]
        store_link = list(df['link'])[i]

        print(f"###################{file_name} 수집 시작###################")

        app = SmartStoreReviewScraper()
        REVIEWS = app.scraped_reviews

        store_data = app.get_store_data(store_link) #스토어 정보 
        json_review = app.get_review_json(store_data['merchant_no'], store_data['product_no'], 1) #리뷰 정보 리퀘스트 
        
        review_data = app.get_review_data(json_review) #해당 아이템 리뷰 (총 아이템수 + 총 페이지수) 정보 
        total_element = review_data['totalElements'] #총 아이템수
        total_pages = review_data['totalPages'] #총 페이지수
        print(f'총 아이템 수: {total_element}\n총 페이지 수: {total_pages}')

        review_content = app.get_review_content(json_review) #목표 데이터
        app.scrape_review_contents(REVIEWS, review_content) #첫 페이지 크롤링

        if self.limit >= total_element or self.limit == 0:
            self.start_scraper(app, REVIEWS, total_element, total_pages, store_data, file_name)
        else:
            self.start_scraper(app, REVIEWS, self.limit, total_pages, store_data, file_name)
            
            

def start_scraper(self, app, REVIEWS, LIMIT, PAGES, store_data, file_name):
    print('목표 데이터 양:'+str(LIMIT)) 

    DF = pd.DataFrame([], columns=self.target_variable)

    while len(REVIEWS) < LIMIT:
        for page in trange(2, PAGES+1, desc="크롤링 진행도"): 
            #첫 페이지는 이미 크롤링 완료하였으니 두번째 페이지부터 시작
            json = app.get_review_json(store_data['merchant_no'], store_data['product_no'], page)
            content = app.get_review_content(json)
            app.scrape_review_contents(REVIEWS, content)
            time.sleep(self.delay_time) 
            if len(REVIEWS) >= LIMIT:
                break

    for i in trange(len(REVIEWS), desc='데이터 변환 중'):
        row = pd.DataFrame([REVIEWS[i]], columns=self.target_variable)
        DF = DF.append(row, ignore_index=True)

    DF.insert(0, column='번호', value=DF.index+1)
    print("<데이터 프레임 샘플>")
    print(DF.head())
    print('데이터 수집 완료! 크롤링된 아이템 수:'+str(len(DF))+'\n')
    DF.to_csv(f'output/data/{file_name}.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

This is the code that goes into my tkinter root buttons. I have to stop the Reader object, but I don't know how to do that. I'm new to threading, so I don't understand the whole mechanics behind. I'm reading documentation every time I have. But could anyone suggest me a quick solution to this? Since I'm kind of running out of time.

```
class Controller(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.thread = None
    self.stop_thread = Event()

def scraping(self):
    while not self.stop_thread.is_set():
        Reader(FILENAME[-1], limit=limit.get(), delay_time=delay_time.get())
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'finished crawling')
        break
        if self.stop_thread.is_set():
            break

def start(self):
    self.stop_thread.clear()
    self.thread = Thread(target = self.scraping)
    self.thread.start()

def stop(self):
    self.stop_thread.set()
    self.thread.join()
    self.thread = None

control = Controller()
search_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
start_btn = tk.Button(root, text='시작', command=control.combine)
start_btn.grid(row=2, column=2)
stop_btn = tk.Button(root, text='중지', command=control.stop)
stop_btn.grid(row=3, column=2)
```

I get that I have to insert a some kind of stop function inside the Reader. But I don't know how I should do that. Any kind of help would be extremely helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the event to the reader object.

```
def __init__(self, filename, limit=None, delay_time=0, stop_thread):
     self.stop_thread = stop_thread   # store event reference
     ........


def extract_file(self):
    df = pd.read_csv('output/wd.csv', encoding='utf-8', names=['names', 'link'])
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if self.stop_thread.is_set(): return  # check event
        ..................


Reader(FILENAME[-1], limit=limit.get(), delay_time=delay_time.get(), self.stop_thread) # pass event to reader
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try it and let you know

Comment: how do I make the Reader to check stop_thread each time? because if you pass in self.stop_thread, it's stable.

Comment: 'each time'? Check the event in every loop and exit the loop if event is set.

Comment: I've edited the code a little. I let the extract_file function to take in stop_thread not the whole object. I think there needs a conditional statement that wraps up the function. I posted an additional answer below, could you check it? Thanks, I think this is a good start.

Comment: It does, by item. But the problem is after I click the stop button the program just freezes. The stop button doesn't pop backup. So it basically feels the same as clicking the exit button. I want the stop button to pop back up, so I can click the start button again. Do you have any ideas about making that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
    def scraping(self):
    file_reader = Reader(FILENAME[-1], limit=limit.get(), delay_time=delay_time.get())
    file_reader.extract_file(self.stop_thread)
    messagebox.showinfo('info', 'finished crawling')
```

I've edited changes to my code thanks to, @Mike67. I think there should be a conditional statement that wraps up the `file_reader.extract_file(self.stop_thread)` to check `stop_thread` for every input items. Any other advice would be truly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding print statements in the code to find out where the code stops. You can also debug it using an IDE (PyCharm\Spyder\VSCode) and step through the code.

Comment: I debugged it, and found out that after I click the stop button, the program stops right after returning line3 (file_reader.extract_file). The program freezes when it should be returning me the messagebox.

Comment: The MessageBox probably blocks because its running in a background thread and there's no way for you to click OK. Try using `print` instead.

Comment: I missed that! How could I miss that! I really appreciate it, man. Thanks!!!